# Do I need to return an object of all the concrete classes implementing an interface if I am using Factory Pattern

Tags: oop, design-patterns, factory-pattern

While reviewing the code for one of my colleagues, I pointed out some code structuring improvements and how we should use Factory Design Pattern for our use-case but I have not been able to convince him so I am seeking help from the almighty community here whose opinion no developer would neglect :)

The code is structured similar to the below psuedocode -

```
abstract class X {
    abstract y();
}

class a extends X {
    y();
}

class b extends X {
    y(){
       factory().y();
    }
}

class factory(){
    determineClass(input){
        if(input == 'a')
           return new a();
        else return null;
    }

}
```

I have two questions -

1. Given that both class a, b extend class x and we are using factory class to determine which object to create, should it not ideally have an extra condition for when input == 'b' and we return new b() ?
2. I don't think class b should extend x because it seems as if we are using this to determine which object to create and call method y() on that class. I think this should be a high level class which calls factory and not an extension of X

Comment: It doesn't look like java. Please put correct tags.

Comment: Please hover over the [factory-pattern] tag to read its description. I suggest that learning about the various factory patterns can help you make a decision here.

Comment: @talex Its just pseudocode

Comment: @jaco0646 Thanks I read the description and understand its bit ambiguous. I am talking about factory pattern in general.

Comment: Your pseudocode makes it difficult to distinguish where you define methods and where you call them.

Comment: A factory should implement what it needs to. Whether or not B is-a X is a separate question; we have no way of knowing. Whether or not this usage of a factory makes sense—no way to know from what’s provided.